# Why am I unable to see the hover effect in the browser

Tags: html, css, hover

Why am I unable to see the hover effect I have applied?
When hovering through the respective element, I cannot see the styles I have applied.
But yes, if I am copying this bunch of code in codepen it is clearly visible, and it's getting applied. But why in browser I cannot see anything

hover on **startButton** and **learnMore-btn** in browser it will not work. but open the code pen file and hoer on **startButton** and **learnMore-btn**

```css
.button-section .startButton {
  background-color: var(--bg-orange);
  border: none;
  color: var(--font-color-white);
}

.button-section .learnMore-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--bg-white);
  color: var(--font-color-white);
}

.button-section .startButton:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid var(--bg-orange);
  color: var(--bg-orange);
}

.button-section .learnMore-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--bg-orange);
  border: 2px solid var(--bg-orange);
  color: var(--font-color-white);
}
```

```html
<section class="mainpart">
  <div class="main-part-container maxWidth padding-left-right">
    <div class="main-partOne">
      <h1>Play Game Everytime Always Be Winner And Strong</h1>
      <p>Improve your gaming skills by playing games that are currently popular so that you don't go out of style improve skills</p>

      <div class="button-section">

        <button type="button" class="startButton">
            Get Started
          </button>
        <button type="button" class="learnMore-btn">
            Learn More
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-partTwo">
      <img src="./Assets/Icons/playButton.svg" alt="">
      <h1>The king of terania And Last Seasion XXIV
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Just look at my codepen file it's working

```
https://codepen.io/DeepakKumarDKN/pen/GRYrQjx
```

Comment: When you say “in browser”, are you linking to the CSS in the `<head>` of your HTML document? Codepen does that part for you. Perhaps that’s it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You don't appear to have defined any of your CSS dynamic properties.

Answer (score -1):

i Checked Your Code and Find Out You are Missing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` in Your Html Document if You Use Codepen it Will Do it For You Automatically, **Create File and named index.html** and Paste The Html Code that i Edited, and then **create style.css File** and Paste The CSS Code, Done

**Note:** i did Not Edited Your Design Just Fixed The Problem

CSS Code

```css
:root {
    --bg-light-black: #0000;
    --bg-black: #000000;
    --bg-white: #ffffff;
    --bg-orange: #fc4242;
    --bg-orange-light: #f69d9d;

    --font-color-white: #ffff;
    --font-color-black: #141414;
    --font-color-darkgrey: #434542;
    --font-color-grey: #99a097;
    --font-color-orange: #ff6263;
}


.button-section .startButton {
    background-color: var(--bg-orange);
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    color: var(--font-color-white);
}

.button-section .learnMore-btn {
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid var(--bg-white);
    color: var(--font-color-white);
}

.button-section .startButton:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid var(--bg-orange);
    color: var(--bg-orange);
}

.button-section .learnMore-btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--bg-orange);
    border: 2px solid var(--bg-orange);
    color: var(--font-color-white);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="mainpart">
        <div class="main-part-container maxWidth padding-left-right">
            <div class="main-partOne">
                <h1>Play Game Everytime Always Be Winner And Strong</h1>
                <p>Improve your gaming skills by playing games that are currently popular so that you don't go out of
                    style improve skills</p>

                <div class="button-section">

                    <button type="button" class="startButton">
                        Get Started
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="learnMore-btn">
                        Learn More
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-partTwo">
                <img src="./Assets/Icons/playButton.svg" alt="">
                <h1>The king of terania
                    And Last Seasion
                    XXIV</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```